# Mysql: Execute query for each date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using `Mysql 5.5.43-0+deb7u1`.

I have managed to create this query to fetch rain data for particular day (I use `MOD`because rain data is updated at every full hour while other data gets update more frequently.)

```
SELECT date,SUM(rainmm) FROM weather WHERE MOD(minute(time),60)=0 AND date=CURDATE()-1;
+------------+-------------+
| date       | sum(rainmm) |
+------------+-------------+
| 2015-06-23 |     0.1     |
+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.15 sec)
```

I am looking for a way to get results for all days with single query instead of needing to check every day manually. I am unsure if I should use loops and iterate number for days from current date or if there is better way to accomplish this.

Desired result:

```
SELECT date, [Smart query to get all days at once]
+------------+-------------+
| date       | sum(rainmm) |
+------------+-------------+
| 2015-06-23 |     0.1     |
| 2015-06-24 |     0.0     |
|    ...     |     ...     |
| 2015-11-11 |     11.1    |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Could you supply your table structure. It's not too clear. Also you could probably group by the mod result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want

```
SELECT date,SUM(rainmm) FROM weather WHERE MOD(minute(time),60)=0
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for.